# Is it possible to send data to Google Analytics service by url?

Tags: google-analytics

I've been trying to send data to Google Analytics through url, but it's not working.

Here is the url:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif?utmac=MY-UA
&utmn=0.57942900+13058623924dd5e0f88d784
&utmp=%2Fmypage.html
&utmr=http%3A%2F%2Fpp.test%2Fmypage-ref.html
&utmdt=test+ga&utmul=en-us
&utmhn=pp.test
&utmcc=__utmz%3D1.1304060743.1.1.utmcsr%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmccn%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd%3D%28none%29%3B+__utma%3D1.100229728.1304060743.1304060743.1304060743.1%3B+__utmz%3D185677488.1304391672.1.1.utmcsr%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmccn%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd%3D%28none%29%3B+__utma%3D185677488.2126025763.1304391672.1304667350.1305106191.6%3B+PHPSESSID%3Dpghin7v4q3g5lssq5c5mjchfj6
&utmcn=1
&utmcr=1
&utmwv=1
&utmsr=1280x1024
&utmsc=32-bit
&utmcs=-
&utmje=0
```

I have been trying follow the parameter here http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsOverview.html

I call the url by curl and tested through the address bar, but not working, no data in my Google Analytics :(

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, although if you're trying to do it you're probably doing something wrong.

But there's more to it than you can see at first sight. The best way to achieve it is to use a mobile library for Google Analytics. Google already provides this for a couple of languages. These libraries are built to send data to Google Analytics via your server. And if you check the server code you'll see that there are some calculations involved. You can possibly change one of these libraries to be run without a request. They're not complicated.

http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm testing, let see if there is data in my google analytic :-)